# DB ERROR: SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela temporária com dados de times de futebol, mas fico recebendo esse erro:

> DB ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ) and t.situacaojogador = 'ativo'

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que está errado? Segue meu código.

```
$sql = "select codtime from jogador where codjogador=" . $_SESSION['codjogador'] . ";";
$rst = my_query($connR, $sql);
if(count($rst) > 0) {
    $codtimejogadorlogado = $rst[0]['codtime'];
} else {
    $codtimejogadorlogado = -1;
}

if($codtimejogadorlogado == '') {
    $codtimejogadorlogado = '-1';
}


$sql = "create temporary table tmptime as
    (select t.codtime, t.nome, j.codjogador
    from time t
    left join jogador j on j.codtime=t.codtime
    where j.codtime in ($codtimejogadorlogado) and t.situacaojogador = 'ativo');";
my_execute($connR, $sql);
```

Resolvido, coloquei mais um if pra verificar se o codtime estava vazio. Código atualizado.

Comment: Sim... quando um jogador sai de um time eu mudo esse valor para 'inativo'

Comment: Qual a versão do `MySQL` que você está utilizando?

Comment: uso a versão 5.7.14